# How to test after_create method in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I have after_create method as follow:

company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

    after_create :create_subscriptions

    def create_subscriptions        
             subscription=Subscription.create(:company_id => self.id, :subscription_dt => Date.today,  :is_active => 'Y', :last_renewal_dt => Date.today + 2,:user_id => self.users.first.id)
             subscription.save        
       end

end
```

While i create a company after_create method called and enter data in subscription table.

In rspec I created company and it success fully created. But how do test "create_subscriptions" method? whoch call in after create. Can i do query in rspec code? like

rspec code:

```
 @company = create(:company)
 @sub = Subscription.find(:first,:conditions => ['company_id= ?', @company.id] ) 
 expect(@sub.company_id).should eq(@company.id)
```

is it ok?? I did not see this type of query in rspec code in my google searching. Have use stub or mock in this?

can anyone please guide me?  I think i have to use stub and mock but i don't know how to use them?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct but your code looks "obsolete" (for Rails 2.x)

I can suggest the following variant

```
@company = create(:company)
@company.reload
expect(@company.subscriptions).not_to be_empty

# additionally you can test attributes
subscription = @company.subscriptions.first
expect(subscription.is_active).to eq('Y')
```

PS it is necessary to add `has_many :subscriptions` to `Company` and `belongs_to` to `Subscription`

Comment: Thanks, so you mean we can use query to fetch test data and compare it in rspec. But most of rspec example i did not found fetch data from database so i have a doubt. But thanks for you help. I modified code as follow:
   subscription = @company.subscription    
   expect(subscription.company_id).to eq(@company.id)